# How can I have composite primary key schema in JugglingDB?

Tags: mysql, schema, jugglingdb

I have a table in mysql that has a composite primary key.How can i define this schema in jugglingDB.

```
var User = schemaDynamo.define('User', {
userId : { type: Number},
deptId : {type: Number} ....
```

column userId and deptId together make the primary key.